# Group parallel calls in RX Java

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

Does anyone know how to execute the following:
The content of an element must be parsed and the sub-elements must be grouped by making a parallel query
You should advance to the next item in the list only if the group query was previously completed

```
Element element = new Element(); 
element1.get(0) = urlA
element1.get(1) = urlB
element1.get(2) = urlC

List<Element> list = new ArrayList();
list.get(0); //consult in parallel  [urlA, urlB, urlC]

//You must wait for the previous query to finish
list.get(1); //consult in parallel  [urlX, urlY, urlZ]
```

I currently use rxjava-3.0.3

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) [image: concatMap marble diagram] operator

So the code may look like this

```
Flowable.fromIterable(list)
.concatMap(element -> Flowable.just(0, 1, 2)
  .map(index -> element.get(index))
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .flatMap(url -> doParsingInParallel(url)))
.doOnNext(parsingResult -> handleParsingResult(parsingResult));
```